# program that read file and extract word without # in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i read a file and file format is this
**INPUT FILE FORMAT**

```
        id          PosScore  NegScore       Word                             SynSet   

        00002098    0         0.75           unable#1                         (usually followed by `to') not having the necessary means or skill or know-how; "unable to get to town without a car"; "unable to obtain funds"
        00002312    0.23      0.43           dorsal#2 abaxial#1               facing away from the axis of an organ or organism; "the abaxial surface of a leaf is the underside or side facing away from the stem"
        00002527    0.14      0.26           ventral#2 adaxial#1              nearest to or facing toward the axis of an organ or organism; "the upper side of a leaf is known as the adaxial surface"
        00002730    0.45      0.32           acroscopic#1                     facing or on the side toward the apex
        00002843    0.91      0.87           basiscopic#1                     facing or on the side toward the base
        00002956    0.43      0.73           abducting#1 abducent#1           especially of muscles; drawing away from the midline of the body or from an adjacent part
        00003131    0.15      0.67           adductive#1 adducting#1 adducent#1  especially of muscles; bringing together or drawing toward the midline of the body or toward an adjacent part    
in this file
```

in this file the Synset column should be delete and second thing if the Word column have more than one word then the id, PosScore, NegScore will be repeat according to word repeat in a line but the id , posScore,NegScore will be same.
i want the following output of the above file
**OUTPUT**

```
 id         PosScore      NegScore              Word     
00002098    0             0.75              unable#1    
00002312    0.23          0.43               dorsal#2    
00002312    0.23          0.43               abaxial#1       
00002527    0.14          0.26               ventral#2    
00002527    0.14          0.26               adaxial#1     
00002730    0.45          0.32               acroscopic#1    
00002843    0.91          0.87               basiscopic#1    
00002956    0.43          0.73               abducting#1    
00002956    0.43          0.73               abducent#1    
00003131    0.15          0.67               adductive#1    
00003131    0.15          0.67               adducting#1    
00003131    0.15          0.67               adducent#1
```

i write the following code but it give unexpected result.

```
 TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("D:\\output.txt");    
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Zia Ur Rehman\Desktop\records.txt");
                string line;
                String lines = "";
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    String[] str = line.Split('\t');

                    String[] words = str[4].Split(' ');
                    for (int k = 0; k < words.Length; k++)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (i + 1 != str.Length)
                            {
                                lines = lines + str[i] + ",";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lines = lines + words[k] + "\r\n";

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            tw.Write(lines);
            tw.Close();
            reader.Close();    
        }
```

this code give the following result which is wrong

```
00002098,0,0.75,unable#1,unable#1
00002312,0,0,dorsal#2 abaxial#1,dorsal#2
00002312,0,0,dorsal#2 abaxial#1,abaxial#1
00002527,0,0,ventral#2 adaxial#1,ventral#2
00002527,0,0,ventral#2 adaxial#1,adaxial#1
00002730,0,0,acroscopic#1,acroscopic#1
00002843,0,0,basiscopic#1,basiscopic#1
00002956,0,0,abducting#1 abducent#1,abducting#1
00002956,0,0,abducting#1 abducent#1,abducent#1
00003131,0,0,adductive#1 adducting#1 adducent#1,adductive#1
00003131,0,0,adductive#1 adducting#1 adducent#1,adducting#1
00003131,0,0,adductive#1 adducting#1 adducent#1,adducent#1
```

Comment: What is "unexpected" ?

Comment: How do you know when a new column begins?

Comment: @Magnus i edit it now you can see

Comment: @GertArnold i edit it now you can see the unexpected result

Comment: looks good except `str[4]`. it should be `str[3]` i think.

Comment: @syedmohsin if you you have an idea about the code then send me the correct code. thanks

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your code and made it to work correctly.
It still lacks validation, can be more performant by using `StringBuilder` and especially by writing each line to file instead of appending it to String. It also lacks `exception handling`.

```
using (TextWriter tw = File.CreateText(@"c:\temp\result.txt"))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"stackov1.txt"))
{
    string line;
    String lines = "";
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        String[] str = line.Split('\t');

        String[] words = str[3].Split(' ');
        for (int k = 0; k < words.Length; k++)
        {
            lines = lines + str[0] + "\t" + str[1] + "\t" + str[2] + "\t" + words[k] + "\r\n";
        }
    }
    tw.Write(lines);
}
```

Comment: I added writer and reader code so now my example is complete (before it required IO to be initialized). Please post detailed information if something is wrong with it

Comment: Sir i add IO but it does not write the file

Comment: Zia, please replace stackov1.txt with a full path to your data file. Also, please use debugger to check what is going wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is working now. after long hard work. 
**Note:** If you don't use proper tabing in your input file. the result will be incorrect. Don't ignore the proper tabing.

```
  TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("D:\\output.txt");    
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Mohsin\Desktop\records.txt");
        string line;
        String lines = "";
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            String[] str = line.Split('\t');

            String[] words = str[3].Split(' ');
            for (int k = 0; k < words.Length; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    if (i + 1 != 4)
                    {
                        lines = lines + str[i] + "\t";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lines = lines + words[k] + "\r\n";

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        tw.Write(lines);
        tw.Close();
        reader.Close();
  }
```